# Discord.py not running off Visual studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Every time I run my discord bot in Visual Studio Code, I get this error. Does anyone know how to fix this? I run macOS Cataline(10.15.7) and Python 3.9.1.

```
dillonbarnes@Downstairs-iMac Iyioid % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/dillonbarnes/Downloads/Iyioid/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 969, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1081, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1111, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Downloads/Iyioid/main.py", line 276, in <module>
    client.run("NzkzNTM5NDUyMTMwOTUxMTg4.X-tvNA.efQG5c4kLA1Z_c8k3TaUJ7Fs0sQ")
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1051, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1020, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/dillonbarnes/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 971, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]
```

I have pip installed discord.py and all of the imports in my code.

Comment: I already mentioned that. MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Navigate to your `Applications/Python 3.X/ folder `
Double click `Install Certificates.command.`

Comment: I did that and got the same error when I ran the code.

Comment: I can't help then, sorry!

Comment: @DillonBarnes Does it happen only on Visual Code?

Comment: I haven't tested. I can't run the code through anything other than VSC on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with **SSL** in **macOS**.

I suggest doing the following:

1. Install the *certifi* package using *pip*. This package basically consist on a set of SSL root certificates.

`pip install --upgrade certifi`

If that does not completely solve the problem, after installing the *certifi* package from pip, execute the file **Install Certificates.command** from `Applications/Python 3.9` folder.

This executable file replaces the root certificates of the default Python installation with the ones shipped through the *certifi* package.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried both of the things you have said, but neither of them worked. I still get the same error.